# Orion-LD version 1.15 supports MongoDB 5.* ,

Tags: mongodb, fiware, fiware-orion

We are currently running a Fiware stack (Orion-LD, QuantumLeap, TimeScaleDB) for months now.
Orion-LD is connected to a "production grade" MongoDB in version v5.0.10.

From time to time, we are experiencing issues with Orion-LD which can't connect to MongoDB with such kind of error messages : "New connection socket descriptor (1024) is not less than FD_SETSIZE (1024).", thus blocking the storage of new data.

I am wondering if Orion-LD  is really compatible with MongoDB 5.* ?

Thanks in advance for your reply.
Laurent

OrionLD compatible with MongoDB 5

Comment: A question about the roadmap and support for a specific piece of software doesn't look like it is a *programming* issue, and doesn't make  it a good fit for Stack Overflow. To obtain a proper answer to this, you would be better off raising the question over on [GitHub](https://github.com/FIWARE/context.Orion-LD/issues) where the  Orion-LD development team will be able to answer directly.